react-hook-form custom validation issue
I'm trying to validate the input after the API request. It looks like value hasErrors is not updated within a validation function. Only after the rerender it gets the value.
And - yes I tried many things like useCallback, setting the state to force rerender
Maybe you can spot the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hj9vsw?file=src%2FApp.tsx
I tried to do the same with formik and swr and got it working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-2ccgg9?file=src%2FApp.tsx
Finally, it works now - special thank-you goes to AI for the ideas
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dzd5wd?file=src%2FApp.tsx

I'm sorry, did AI answer your question? If not, can you be more precise with what the problem is?

Your first example fails because all of the error states returned from useQuery are stateful & asynchronous, but your validation function is synchronously calling refetch and then immediately trying to read those error values.

AI just a hack, {...register('example', { validate: async (value) => await validate(value) })} if I wait for refetch still did not work

So the reason why simply awaiting refetch doesn't work is because those error values are both async and stateful. When state updates the new value is available only on the next render.  But you're trying to read state updates in the middle of a function call.  While that function is running, it can't read state updates.

You could do this const result = await refetch()  then read the properties of result.  Result is async, but not stateful.

Open a demo and add await - then in the input add a number in the domain name so it will become invalid - and this will still not show that input is invalid

So the problem was in a different spot. Make sure that your custom hooks are correctly returning values. If you extract them before returning - they loose track of changes.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-gpdnjb?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Here is a solution using async await in the validate method.  awaiting refetch.   You can cause this error by passing in id 0.  It's a small tweak to your first example.
const validate = async (value: string) => {
    if (value.length > 3) {
      const result = await refetch();

      console.log({ result });
      if (!result.data.id) {
        return 'Error no such todo';
      }

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-foxtb6?file=src%2FApp.tsx
The issue you are having is that you are trying to refetch and then read a state update while inside of a function call.
It's the same problem that many people have in React when they update state in a function then immediately try to read that state and discover that state hasn't updated yet.  Changes in state do not show up until the next render. You can't set state in a function then immediately expect to be able to read that updated state in the same function call.  That is what is happening when you call refetch in the validate method.  When refetch resolves it updates state being return from useQuery and you are trying to read those state updates in the same function that called refetch.
In my example, by awaiting  refetch we get the values directly from the result of the refetch. That result is not stateful and can be read immediately.
